# Strange Window popup behaviour on IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup

We have written a small javascript function which checks if a URL should open in same window or a popup. In cases when a url should open in a new window IE is giving some strange behaviour a window popup flashes and closes with a beep sound. Can anybody suggest whats going behind the scenes i do not think its my javascript which is wrong. Is it some browser weird behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, this sounds like some third party stuff. By default IE will try to guess what it should do with popups (open in a popup window, open in a new tab, don't open at all) but it won't try to open a window and close it immediately (unless caused by some addons or code included in the page). JavaScript errors shouldn't cause the window to close either (unless they really call `window.close()`).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have a third party pop-up blocker installed.